# visual studio intellisense returns Body.Name can not be assigned

Tags: c#

Guys check the code bellow. Here i am trying to convert a cURL to c# restsharp code. I already tried to convert it like bellow. But my visual studio intellisense says `request.Body.Name = "request.json";` this line a not valid. Please check my whole RestSharp code and match with cUrl and give me advice whats wrong i did here.

Thanks in advance.

CURL:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/locations/location-id/productSets
```

Restsharp:

```
 RestClient client = new RestClient("https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/locations/location-id/productSets");
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            string cred = @"gcloud auth application-default print-access-token";
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+cred);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.Body.Name = "request.json";//my visual studio intellisense says this line is wrong
            var response = client.Execute(request);
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the actual error, not 'this line is not valid'.

Comment: @Slugsie added as you requested

Comment: @request.json is a reference to the file in curl command. you need to add the actual json from the file to the body using   `request.AddJsonBody(File.ReadAllText("request.json"));`. The visual studio is giving error because you are trying to set a readonly property hence the error.